# Why isn't my lemon tree bearing fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, lemons

My lemon tree used to bear lemons, but since my brother pruned the branches, there are no lemons growing.

What did he do wrong? Did he cut too many branches, or is it something else?

Comment: Can't say, need more info - when did he prune it, where's it growing (ground or pot, indoors or out) how long have you had it?

Comment: or a picture? That would help a lot.

Comment: Hi Jo Ann. Welcome to the site! I've added the tag "lemons" to your question. If you press on it, a list of questions about lemon trees will come up. If you look at those, you might find some answers that may help you.